# Dynamique image of a view inside a button

Tags: image, button, view

I would like to add an image inside a button,but this image shows the current view of one of my views.

If anyone knows how to do.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What platform? What language? What code have you written so far? Can you explain your problem in more detail?

Comment: I knows how to display the current view,i'm calling the component,and cause i'm using the singleton to create my views i get the correct state,but,i would like to resize it to my current size of my button, and freeze all actions.

Comment: Ok sorry,i forget the main things,i'm using C# with WPF ,so i talk about xaml.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<button onClick="window.location='URL' " style="background-color:#FFFFFF"><img src="IMAGE_URL"></button>
```

Comment: Thanks,but i've no url for the source ,because i don't copy the view on local. I'm able to get the view,but i can't freeze the component inside the button,and resize it to my current size of my button

Comment: set height and width for image and put </img>

Comment: Yes i have some images,but,i want to display not an image,but the visual of a view in my app.i'm stuck when i'm trying to bind the visual property to the view i wanted.